# Redirect the URL using .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a page showing the products with the hyperlink for it as

```
 www.domainname.com/productname
```

now my client needs to add store and needs the URL to show as

```
 www.domainname.com/store/productname
```

I have done it via code and now when I click on it for a detail page, its still redirecting to

```
 www.domainname.com/productname
```

but need to be

```
 www.domainname.com/store/productname
```

tried with this:

```
 RewriteRule ^store/?$ domianname.com/?$ [NC,L]
```

in .htaccess file, not sure whether I'm on page

Can any one tell me how to do it via .htaccess file.

Comment: Is `mod_rewrite` enabled in .htaccess?

Comment: yes it enabled Manoj

Answer (score 0):

Your `RewriteRule` is backwards: you need [the path you're matching first, then the path you're redirecting to](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule). Try this:

```
RewriteRule !^/store/(.*) /store/$1 [NC,L]
```

Also, [you don't actually need `mod_rewrite` to do this.](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite) You could try `mod_redirect`, which is simpler and easier to understand:

```
RedirectMatch !^/store/ /store/
```

(N.B. I haven't tried either of these, so I'm not 100% certain they do what you want.)

Comment: thankyou @pjmorse, it doesn't work for me... still expecting any answer